# Bouncing ball-moving opposite direction at the border of the window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intersection

I tried making a bouncing rectangle and I managed to detect the edges/borders of the window/canvas. I tried making the timer stop at the edges and it worked. I defined the edges manually though. My problem is making the rectangle go the opposite direction once it hits the borders. In my code when it reaches the border it just goes back and forth fast and not actually changes position. It sort of shakes in place.

The code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer t;
    int ballvX1, ballvY1, ballvX2, ballvY2;
    public void movement(Rectangle r, int ballvX, int ballvY)
    {
        var BallX = Canvas.GetLeft(r);  //position left
        var BallY = Canvas.GetTop(r);  //position up 
        if((BallX <= 1)||(BallX >= 455))
        {             
            ballvX = -ballvX;
        }
        if((BallY <= 10)||(BallY >= 270))
        {
            ballvY = -ballvY;
        }
         Canvas.SetLeft(r, BallX + ballvX);
         Canvas.SetTop(r, BallY + ballvY);
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(177777);
        t.Tick += T_Tick; ;
    }
    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movement(r1, ballvX1, ballvY1);
        movement(r2, ballvX2, ballvY2);
        var BallX1 = Canvas.GetLeft(r1);  //position left
        var BallY1 = Canvas.GetTop(r1);  //position up 
        Rect r1new = new Rect(BallX1, BallY1, r1.ActualWidth, 
        r1.ActualHeight);
        var BallX2 = Canvas.GetLeft(r2);  //position left
        var BallY2 = Canvas.GetTop(r2);  //position up 
        Rect r2new = new Rect(BallX2, BallY2, r2.ActualWidth, 
        r2.ActualHeight);
        if (r1new.IntersectsWith(r2new))
        {
            t.Stop();
        }

    }

    private void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ballvX1 = rnd.Next(-11, 10);
        ballvY1 = rnd.Next(-11, 10);
        ballvX2 = rnd.Next(-11, 10);
        ballvY2 = rnd.Next(-11, 10);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void b2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
    }

    private void b3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
        Canvas.SetLeft(r1, 172);
        Canvas.SetTop(r1, 146);
        Canvas.SetLeft(r2, 423);
        Canvas.SetTop(r2, 56);
    }
}
}
```

If anyone knows how to fix this I would be extremely grateful. BTW there are 2 rectangles but I gave them both the same function of movement and once they meet they just stop, but I think it's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: When you reverse the directions by `ballvX = -ballvX` and `ballvY = -ballvY` respectively, you're only changing the parameter passed to the `movement` method. That change however has no effect outside the method. You should instead change the member fields `ballvX1` etc. Try passing the fields as reference parameters like `public void movement(Rectangle r, ref int ballvX, ref int ballvY)`. All the values may also better be of type `double` instead of `int`, because that's what WPF calculates with.

Comment: I changed it to ref and it worked thank you so much!I never actually needed to use ref before since i'm kinda a beginner so I wouldn't have thought to do that XD

Comment: It may make sense to have kind of a Ball class with its own fields or properties for its position and velocity (I'd recommend to use Point and Vector), and a Move method that operates on these fields.

Comment: On another note, do you know how I could find the borders of the window/canvas without manually checking?Iv'e tries canvas.Height-r1.Height and same with Width and it sort of worked but wasn't exact so I couldn't really use it, is there a better way?

Comment: Use ActualWidth and ActualHeight and, as said, use double values instead of integers. Calculate the new position before actually moving the object. If the new position is "behind the wall", chance the velocity vector and recalculate the position.

Comment: Ok thanks,you really helped me!